# Deferent result in Unicode to String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, unicodescalar

I am translating my **String** value to **unicodeScalars** with this down code, for example if I gave **"A"** as input I will get **65** as output, now that I know **65** is number of **A**, then I want give **65** to receive **A** again, but it gave **e**, I am sure I am mixing some topic together and also missing something, need some help for understanding why this is deferent and how can I use **"\u{?????}"** for returning my String, thanks

```
let string: String = "A"
let UInt32Value: UInt32 = string.unicodeScalars[string.startIndex].value
print(UInt32Value) // 65


let newString = "\u{65}"
print(newString) // e
```

ps: I know that there is official way of using unicodescalar to get the String back, but I am interested to "\u{?????}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to convert as follows

```
let ans =  String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(65)))
print(ans)
```

I think the problem is, you are converting (A) string -> unicodescalar -> uint

and have to convert (65) uint -> unicodescalar -> string to get the original value

Comment: Yes, I know that, but as I asked in my question I want make this job with  "\u{?????}", do you know how we can do with that as well?

Comment: The use of `UInt8` initializer is pointless. `String(UnicodeScalar(65))` UInt8 conforms to Expressible ByIntegerliteral and Swift is a type inferred language. It will automatically infer the non optional UInt8 initializer

Answer (score 0):

The `\u{...}` escape sequence uses hex:

> Special characters can be included in string literals of both the single-line and multiline forms using the following escape sequences:
>
> - [...]
> - Unicode scalar (`\u{n}`), where n is a hexadecimal number that has one to eight digits

From the [language reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID417).

So you need

```
"\u{41}"
```

Comment: Is it right to say that I must convert 65 to 41 with a func that works with hexadecimal?

Comment: @swiftPunk Just search "65 to hex" on google. Google can do hex conversions these days.

Comment: @swiftPunk Also note that this is a string _literal_, you can't do anything crazy like calling functions/referring to a variable i those `{}` brackets. You can only put, literally, 1 to 8 hexadecimal digits in there.

Comment: @swiftPunk That is to say, if you have the number 65 _at runtime_ (e.g. stored in a variable), you cannot use the `\u{...}` notation. In that case you can use Chandramohan's answer. `\u{...}` is only for when you know the number _at compile time_.

Comment: or using the string radix initializer `String(65, radix: 16)` and in the opposite direction `Int("41", radix: 16)` or literally type `0x41`